# APNs Provider API batch request

Tags: php, ios, curl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm about to rewrite my push services in PHP to work with the new APNs Provider API.
My question is, if there are any best practices in sending one notification to multiple devices...

I already found the solution for sending push notifications with PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"aps":{"alert":"Here I am","sound":"default"}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

But with this code I can send the message to one device, because I have to put the device token in the URL. But I want to send the message to a unknown amount of devices. And unfortunately I couldn't find an endpoint for sending a message to multiple devices.

---

The Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html) says this:

*Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack.*

So I think it's bad practice to put my `CURL request` into a `for-loop`, and loop through all my device tokens.

Anybody any suggestions in how to solve this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on curl, but in general, Apns providers must maintain persistent connections toward Apns Cloud. There is no way to broadcast to multiple devices using single message. Apns providers should take leverage of http/2 (multiple streams per connection) and can also send messages across multiple connections, but must not do connection and disconnection in loop that would be treated as DoS attack.

Avoid the connection loop, you should post the messages in loop, connection/disconnection part must not be part of loop.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
_Ayush

Comment: Can you elaborate how to make multiple streams per connection, perhaps with some example JavaScript code?

Comment: Hi, I am not a java script person. Though I can help you with some reference explaining multiple streams encapsulated in single TCP connection. e.g. Please refer to link -
 https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2/

Answer (score 1):

libcurl automatically attempts to keep a connection open whenever possible. The pattern to follow is to do the following:

1) Create the curl handle: `$ch = curl_init();`

2) Set appropriate options on the handle:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"aps":{"alert":"Here I am","sound":"default"}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
```

3) Begin the for loop, set the url for each recipient and execute the request:

```
for ($tokens as $token) { //Iterate push tokens

    $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/{$token}";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check result, handle errors etc...

   }

   curl_close($ch); // Close connection outside the loop
```

Following the approach above should keep the connection open and comply with Apple's requirements.